# NtQuerySystemInformation returns back negative result for a specific core - What does that mean

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I am trying to output the performance of each processor on my machine.
I have two groups with 36 processors on each. I am doing something like this

```cpp
PVOID WLAlloc(DWORD dwSize)
{
    PVOID pMem = nullptr;
    pMem = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(),NULL,dwSize);
    return pMem;
}

void test()
{
    int numofGroups = 2;
    DWORD uSize = 2 * sizeof(SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION);
    PVOID pMem = WLAlloc(uSize);
    SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION*  m_pCoreUsageInfoArray = (SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION*)pMem;
    NTSTATUS status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessorPerformanceInformation, m_pCoreUsageInfoArray, uSize, NULL);
    if (status >= 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 72; i++) 
        {
            auto t = m_pCoreUsageInfoArray[i];
            std::cout << "Core: " << i << " Idle:" << t.IdleTime.QuadPart << " Kernel: " << t.KernelTime.QuadPart << " User :" << t.UserTime.QuadPart << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this as output:

```
Core: 23 Idle:0 Kernel: -9223358841219038703 User :0
```

Any idea why I am getting a negative number?

Comment: Look at the value of the return value. It is a specific error code.

Comment: In `WLAlloc` the first assignment is pointless. You wouldn't write `x = 1; x = 2;` which is logically equivalent to what you do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are allocating only room for 2 `SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION`, but then you are trying to iterate up to index 72, which is *Undefined Behavior* for indexes 2 and higher.

You need to fix your loop to only iterate over items you have pre-allocated, or else query for the actual size first and retry the call with the proper size:

```cpp
DWORD uSize = 0;

NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessorPerformanceInformation, NULL, 0, &uSize);

PVOID pMem = WLAlloc(uSize);
SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION* m_pCoreUsageInfoArray = (SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION*)pMem;

if (NT_ERROR(NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessorPerformanceInformation, m_pCoreUsageInfoArray, uSize, NULL)))
{
    return;
}

int numofGroups = uSize / sizeof(SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION);

for (int i = 0; i < numofGroups; i++)
{
    auto t = m_pCoreUsageInfoArray[i];
    std::cout << "Core: " << i << " Idle:" << t.IdleTime.QuadPart << " Kernel: " << t.KernelTime.QuadPart << " User :" << t.UserTime.QuadPart << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Note that you are not doing error checking on the 1st call to `NtQuerySystemInformation()`, and if the 2nd call fails then you are leaking the allocated memory.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for clearing this up. numofGroups  is coming up as 36 . How do I display the next 36 ? Is there anything I need to do to switch the groups

Comment: @JamesFranco `SystemProcessorPerformanceInformation` does not support multiple [processor groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/processor-groups). Use [`GetProcessGroupAffinity()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processtopologyapi/nf-processtopologyapi-getprocessgroupaffinity) to loop through the available groups. On each iteration, call [`SetThreadGroupAffinity()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processtopologyapi/nf-processtopologyapi-setthreadgroupaffinity) before calling `NtQuerySystemInformation()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau gotcha. So basically Ill need to run this on a thread that is running on a processor on that group. Is that correct ?

Comment: @JamesFranco You will need to make the thread run on the processor(s) of one group, do the query, then switch the thread's affinity to run on the processor(s) of the next group, do another query, and so on until finished.